# Java Date get CE year

Tags: java, date

I have an instance of `Date`:

```
Date date = new Date();
```

But when I use the `date.getYear()` method:

1. It is deprecated
2. It returns **114** instead of **2014**

What is the best way to get the CE year?

Comment: You could use a `Calendar` or you could format it using `yyyy` pattern depending on what you want to do.  If you're using Java 8, you could even take a look at the new Time API

Comment: The `Date` API in Java is from hell. Look at other APIs like [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), unless you use Java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not get the full form of CE .If you need  year you can get it by

```
int year  = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use formatter to get CE year

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
String strReturn = sdf.format(date);
```

here strReturn will be 2014

Answer (score 1):

## Joda-Time

Using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.5 library in example code below.

## Time Zone

Time zone is crucial to get a date, and therefore a year. At stroke of midnight of New Years Day in Paris, it is still "last year" in Montreal.

```
int year = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) ).getYear();
```